# How to show Json data to Django template?

Tags: python, json, django, django-templates, django-jsonfield

I store **JSON** data to **TextField** :
Data in TextField:

```
[{"id":1,"Name":"AC","Quantity":"12","Weight":"200","WeightTypes":"KG",
 "TotalWeight":"2400","CustomsCharge":"300.0","Subtotal":"3600"},

{"id":2,"Name":"Soap","Quantity":"12","Weight":"500",
 "WeightTypes":"GRAM","TotalWeight":"6","Customs Charge":"0.0","Subtotal":"12"}]
```

I receive data in my **view.py:** using
products = json.loads(data)

After that, i am trying to show each item's in **Django templates**

```
{% for p in products %}
    {% for key, value in p.items %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{value.id}}</td>
                <td>{{value.Name}}</td>
                <td>{{value.Quantity}}</td>
                <td>{{value.CustomsCharge}}</td>
                <td>{{value.Subtotal}}</td>
                
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
            
    {% endfor %}
```

But it's not working!
How can i get each value from this Jason field?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by **not working** ? Explain a bit whats happening.

Comment: Well, actually if i  use`<td>{{value}}</td>` then, i can get the all the value. But if i want to see get only **Name** or only **CustomsCharges** using `<td>{{value.Name}}</td>` then is not giving value. I am willing to access specific  value.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just wrong on parsing the data into template. Basicly you no need to use `p.items` because it will unpack your original dict items values, meanwhile yo just need to directly call on product loops.

```
{% for p in products %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ p.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ p.Name }}</td>
        <td>{{ p.Quantity }} (pcs)</td>
        <td>{{ p.Weight }}</td>
        <td>{{ p.WeightTypes }}</td>
        <td>{{ p.TotalWeight }}</td>
        <td>{{ p.CustomsCharge }}</td>
        <td>{{ p.Subtotal }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```